# Android UX/UI guidelines for smaller vs larger screen size and pixel densities

Tags: gui-design, mobile, screen-resolution, android

I'm an Android Developer that's not all that well versed in UI/UX design principles. In the projects I work on, I find that the biggest issue is accounting for the myriad of screen densities and sizes. Like comparing two devices, a Pixel 3 XL vs a Nexus 5 (Different generations of devices but fits the size issue).

Everything on the Pixel 3 XL looks so much smaller, so for that bigger screen size and density, I should be making controls larger right? What's the design guideline around how to render on a smaller phone vs a larger phone, and a smaller density phone vs a larger one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to UI design and implementation rather than UX

Comment: I think we have tags for questions about GUI design and screen resolution. Properly tagged, this question might be okay here. I agree that it needs to be more 'answerable'; what's asked is for very general advice, which is against the usual SE model of question. OP, can you narrow down your question to something more answerable?

Comment: This is very much on topic, if not particularly well asked. How things fit on the screen (without scrolling) greatly affects usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"so for that bigger screen size and density, I should be making controls larger right?"

NO. It depends. If you are hellbent on achieving the same ratio of whitespace then yes, but that is a stupid endeavor to invest in.

Using Density Independent metrics (dp and sp) will help you to achieve the same physical size of widgets, and that is what is most important. A touch target should be about the size of a thumb print, 48dp achieves that on all devices. Design for touch, usability, and the communication of information first...worry last about balancing whitespace ratios when comparing the same screen across multiple devices at the same time (as that is not a use-case that regular users will be involved in).

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Thank you